Tailwindcss not working for Vite + Vue3 + Primevue
I'm sry if I have a duplicate question. I went through the questions already in the forum, but still couldn't find a solution I haven't tried yet.
Problem explanation
I'm working on a test project right now, to get to get more familiar with different concepts. My project is uses Vue3, Vite, PrimeVue, Pinia, Supabase, (...) and tailwindcss. I added tailwindcss last and based on the documentation I added the configurations to my different config files - still the classes inside my vue components are not working (and tailwindcss isn't really there in dev mode).
After searching for hours over some days and trying different approaches (found on stackOverflow, documentations (...), including the postcss-load-config pakcage) without success, I thought posting here would maybe help to find me a solution. If anyone encountered the same problem or has more expertise on that matter I would be really greatful.
Test-Repo
I put the test project repo to public, because I thought it'd be easier that way: https://github.com/lyra-neska/pkmn-glossar
Tried options:

importing tailwindcss via with @import, @layer or @tailwind
adding tailwindcss to packages in vite.config, ts.config (...) directly
adding from and to properties to tailwind.config.ts
going with different preprocessor setups to configure tailwind and postcss
trying to add postcss-load-config for and postcss.config.ts options

I'm sure I tried more, but I didn't list them all down
Expected outcome

fix the tailwindcss issue to use tailwindcss classes in my vue components

